# Doing something at a particular TIME in .net

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time

I have a process that runs every five minutes and then sleeps.  I am wondering if there is an elegant way to do something (anything) when the time is between 11:45PM and midnight on Day.

My first instinct was to get a do something similar to this...

```
    public bool isItMidNight() {
        return ((DateTime.UtcNow.Hour > 11:54) && DateTime.UtcNow.Hour < 11.59);             
    }
```

If that value evaluates to true, then do something.  If not, keep sleeping and waking un
Just psuedo-code BTW.  I don't think this will get to production.  But that was my idea.  Is there a more **strong text**elegant solution

Comment: I think your best bet here is with a scheduled task, having the code you wish to run inside a Console Application.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if it qualifies as "elegant", but [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is certainly "enterprisey".

Answer (score 2):

Leave the mechanics of time management to the place best suited for it - I'd recommend using the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Let it trigger your application at 11:45 PM and then your application can concentrate on its task without worrying about time and whether another instance of the application has already picked up and run with the task and so on.

Comment: That is something I have considered.  But I am trying to keep the moving parts on this assignment to a minimum.  And since I new that this thread sleeps and wakes up every couple of minutes I was wondering if there was a way I could take advantage of that.

Comment: @DmainEvent along with a mutex/semaphore to make sure that one and only one process kicks off for a given day, you also have to make sure that you have one process alive at the time to do its thing.  Do you have a mechanism defined to make sure that your process will be running between 11:45 and midnight every day?  Will it handle crashes and machine restarts gracefully?  A scheduled task implicitly handles all of these concerns.

Comment: There will be a process running to make sure this thing kicks off.  That thread spins of this thread every 5 minutes.  Again, I have thought of using a scheduled task, but this process was already in place, and I thought I might as well use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Timer` class, something like this one:

```
new System.Threading.Timer(myScheduledTask, null, new TimeSpan(hh, mm, ss) - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, -1);
```

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Now that I have reviewed some code, I am not certain how that solves my particular problem.  I don't necessarily want to count down to anything.  My thread will wake up every 5 minutes.  The one time of the day where it wakes up between a 5 minute interval, I want to do something.  How does the above code help me do that?

Comment: ok, do you mean you want to schedule wake up of existing thread to specific time? do you really need it this separate thread all the other time? why not to use timer instead that thread - it may accept state object..

Comment: Well, the thread already wakes up at certain times.  It wakes up every 5 minutes every day.  If the thread wakes up at a time lets say 2:30 pm central time, if it is between 2:29 and 2:34 let say I write "yip Skippee" to the console.  If the time is 2:36 when the thread wakes up, it does what it does and goes back to sleep.

Comment: so, you are asking about elegant way to check if current time inside particular range?

Comment: That is almost exactly like what I am trying to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27503/discussion-between-dmainevent-and-lanorkin)